# Boostrap table change icon by fontAwesome by icon bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Based on this link : https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#icons
I tried to change the icon font awesome by bootstrap 5 icon

Thank you

inside the table attributes, I added but it doesn't work. Not sure I understand well the process

```
<table
  id="table"
  data-icons= "toggleOff: 'bi bi-alarm',
  toggleOn: 'bi bi-alarm',
  columns: 'bi bi-alarm'"
  data-toggle="table"
  data-height="460"
>
```

Comment: Could you explain what doesn't work, and what you try to achieve (what's the expected result)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table options are defined in `jQuery.fn.bootstrapTable.defaults`, which means you should add changes to your *.js file not in html as css

Try it overwriting someting like this:

```
 $.extend($.fn.bootstrapTable.defaults.icons, {
       toggleOff: 'bi bi-alarm',
       toggleOn: 'bi bi-alarm',
       columns: 'bi bi-alarm'
 });
```